# QImage from datastream

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qimage

I'm using the Qt library, creating QImages.

I'm able to use [this constructor](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html#QImage-10):

```
QImage image("example.jpg");
```

But I'm having trouble with [this static function](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html#fromData-2):

```
char buffer[sizeOfFile];
ifstream inFile("example.jpg");
inFile.read(buffer, sizeOfFile);
QImage image = QImage::fromData(buffer); // error here
// but there's nothing wrong with the buffer
ofstream outFile("bufferOut.jpg");
outFile.write(buffer, sizeOfFile);
```

Where Qt spits out to console:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
JPEG datastream contains no image
```

The above isn't *exactly* what I have, but it's the only important difference. (I need to be able to read from a buffer because I'm opening images that are inside a zip archive.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tnx to peppe from #qt on irc.freenode.net:

The solution is to explicitly include the buffer length. Ignoring a few `unsigned char` to `char` typecasting and other details, what I should have used is something akin to:

```
QImage image = QImage::fromData(buffer, sizeOfFile);
```

Comment: You and Pepe are the dudes!